# Searching records between today's date and a specified month of this year

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to search records between today's date and a specified month of this year. If i wanted to perform the same query next year without altering the query, then the month has to be based from sysdate I think? This is what I am trying to achieve anyway. Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM details n
WHERE n.id (SELECT p.nhno 
            FROM patient p 
            WHERE p.fname = 'James'
            AND p.surname = 'Gump'
            AND p.nhno = n.nhno
            AND n.daterecorded 
            BETWEEN '01-OCT-15' AND to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yy'))
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  How does the "specified month" relate to the current date?  Do you want, for example, to search for rows between the first of the month two months ago and midnight today?

Comment: sorry basically the year has to be from the sysdate

Comment: Still not following.  In your question, you have the predicate `BETWEEN '01-OCT-15' AND to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yy')`.  I assume this is what we're talking about.  My guess is that you are trying to come up with a way to calculate the date 1 October 2015 at midnight based on the current date.  That's why I'm asking you what the algorithm is.  Do you want the first of the month 2 months ago?  The first of the current quarter?  Something else?

Comment: Is `daterecord` a string or a date? You are comparing it as a string but that does not make sense as it will do an text comparison and trying to find a string value between `'01-OCT-15'` and `'01-DEC-15'` will fail since the latter is before the former (i.e. `O` > `D`). And that is only the start of the issues you will get doing a text comparison.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM details n
WHERE n.id (SELECT p.nhno 
            FROM patient p 
            WHERE p.fname = 'James'
            AND p.surname = 'Gump'
            AND p.nhno = n.nhno
            AND n.daterecorded 
            BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-OCT-'||(SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) FROM DUAL),'DD-MON-YY') 
                AND TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY');
```

Comment: `'01-OCT-2015'` is a string not a date - the only way this will work is if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `DD-MON-YYYY` however, if it isn't or it gets changed then it will not work.

Comment: In addition to the NLS issues, it seems unlikely that this is what the individual wants.  If you run this any time before October 1 in a given year, you'll get no results (assuming your NLS settings allow the query to run).  That seems unlikely to be the desired outcome

Comment: Thanks, sorry I did not test it out. I have fixed it and tested it, works as expected. Please thumbs up if you like it.

Comment: extract year from sysdate does not return a four digit number? why you use YY format?

Comment: When I tried YYYY format it was returning 0015 instead of 2015, so YY worked best in this case. @FlorinGhita

Answer (score 0):

What u are inferring above is not correct. U have given a date of '01-oct-15' and u want to run the same query without altering 
the date for next year also. And what you think the result would be? U will be getting the records from '01-oct-15' to every year u run the query not a specific month in the same year!

As u said above, u seemed to need only records for a specified month of the same year but not the same '01-oct-15' for every year.

IF U NEED RECORDS BETWEEN 2 MONTHS(BEFORE) AND TODAY, USE BELOW QUERY,

```
SELECT *
  FROM details n
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.nhno 
                 FROM patient p 
                WHERE p.fname = 'James'
                  AND p.surname = 'Gump'
                  AND p.nhno = n.nhno
                  AND p.daterecorded BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2) AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yy'));
```

IF U NEED RECORDS BETWEEN 2 MONTHS(AFTER) AND TODAY, REPLACE THE BETWEEN STATEMENT IN THE ABOVE QUERY WITH,

```
'BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 2) AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yy'))'
```

U can also alter this query in 'add_months' to the specified month u need.
Say, if u want records between 6 months(before) and present date,

```
'BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6) AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yy'))'
```

U can run this query every year without any alterations.

This should do it. If not, get back to me.